# Como sumar la primera y ultima posicion de un array

Tags: c++, dev-c++

El problema es este:

Dado un arreglo de  enteros donde  es par, escribe un programa que sume (en parejas) los elementos de lados opuestos del arreglo: el primer elemento con el último, el segundo elemento con el penúltimo, etc.

Y esto es lo que llevo:

```
introducir el código aquí
int a;
int suma=0;

cin>>a;

int arr[a];
int brr[a/2];

for(int i=0; i<a; i++){
    cin>>arr[i];
}

for(int i=0; i<a; i++){
    if(a <= 2){
        suma += arr[i];
        cout<<suma;
        break;
    }else{
        suma = arr[i] + arr[i-a];
        cout<<brr[suma]<<" ";
        break;
    }
}
```

En el else es donde esta mi duda como le puedo hacer para que vaya incrementado la posicion de la primera parte de la suma del arreglo y como le puedo hacer para que vaya decrementando la segunda parte de la suma del arreglo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < a/2; i++)
{
    suma = arr[i] + arr[a - 1 - i];
    //Imprimir suma.
}
```

Se hace un **ciclo for** que recorra el arreglo hasta la mitad de su tamaño, y entonces se van sumando las posiciones opuestas, las posiciones iniciales se obtienen a través de:

```
arr[i]
```

y las opuestas a través de:

```
arr[a - 1 - i]
```

Al tamaño total del arreglo que está representado por la **variable a** se le resta **1** ya que en **C++** los arreglos empiezan en la posición **0**, y posteriormente se le resta el índice actual por donde va el **ciclo for**.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvio bastante

Comment: @ed_sgs si la respuesta te resulto util te agradeceria que la marcaras como aceptada, gracias